# Django - start with queryset of all records, then remove some based on consecutive filters?

Tags: django

Let's say I have a model that looks like this:

```
My Model:
  isBig = Boolean
  isRound = Boolean
  isBlue = Boolean
  isStraight = Boolean
```

Now, I need to get a specific filtered set of these records. I might need the set that has `isBig=True` and `isBlue=True` or I may need the set that has *all* fields set to true. And maybe another time, I need to have the set that has all fields set to false. Basically I don't know what I'll need until runtime.

Since making a query using a bunch of `.filter`s chained together is not feasible (with only 4 fields, there are 256 different combinations, and my actual model has like 8 fields) my approach is like this so far, but it isn't giving me what I want:

```
# start with all records
myQS = My_Model.objects.all()
# peel off a group of records based on each criteria
if not isBig:
  myQS = myQS.exclude(isBig=False)
if not isRound:
  myQS = myQS.exclude(isRound=False)
if not isBlue:
  myQS = myQS.exclude(isBlue=False)
if not isStraight:
  myQS = myQS.exclude(isStraight=False)
```

So, I start with all the records, then move through each field trying to make `myQS` smaller and smaller, peeling off the records I don't want.

Why isn't this working, and how is my logic off?

**EDIT** Changed my `if` statements to avoid assignment.

For clarity, when I say "isn't working" the results I get are exactly opposite of what I would expect. So, if I wanted all the records that contain `isBlue = True` and nothing else, I actually get all the records where all fields are `True` and `isBlue = False` - exactly opposite of what I'd expect.

Comment: There's nothing fundamentally wrong with this approach. That is exactly how it should work.

Print `myQs.query` to debug what the generated query is. Also, we need a better definition of "isn't working"

Comment: My be you should try myQS.exclude(isBig=True) etc?

Comment: @ makamok Ya, I think with the double *double* negatives, I was getting all turned around. I went with the simpler solution of `if isBig == True`. Works now :)